# What kind of webprograming language is this? <!-- -->

Tags: html

I'm an old hand on programming but a wet-behind-the-ears newbie on webprogramming. I ran in to this in a project and I need help identifying the technique/language used.

It is some sort of dynamic web-page that fetches information from a database and displays it in a table. In the html-page that is used these tags are

```
 <!--  some text that has to be some form of commands -->
```

What is it called? It is impossible to google either the starting tag or the closing tag :/
I know that it somehow uses a c-program to do the actual fetching of the data, but i'm at a loss how it actually works.

What I need is the name so I know what to look for in the form of online resources to learn this and I do hope that this kind of tag-usage is only used by one type of language/technique :)

thanks in advance from archie!

Comment: It's an HTML comment... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_Importance_of_Correct_HTML_Commenting

Comment: And if you want more information about the langauge WITHIN THE CMOMENT - guess what, give us an example.

Comment: @TomTom Well I didn't ask about what was inside of the tags now did I? I asked about the tags themself so guess what? Question answered.

Comment: ;) then my advice: learn html (reading the spec, old fashioned) ;)

Comment: :P Yeah, as I said - I'm a wet-behind-the-ears newbie when it comes to webdevelopment. But I guess that after 18 years of webusage it's time to learn something about the mechanics behind it, especially if i want the current software project to come out nice. So I read through the HTML standard last night and now I'm submerging into the more advanced stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those tags are just html comments.  It's possible that they're being used in a template file, and a server-side scripting language is doing some kind of search/replace to execute commands on the template. If so, it's impossible to say what language it is.

Comment: That they are comments is all I need to know since that makes the rest of the project I'm examining more understandable. Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an HTML comment

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp

Comment: in addition, xaml uses it too!

Comment: While it may appear that way, I don't believe he posted any actual code.  I believe he is asking what the code is that he didn't post.

Comment: How are they a horrible source?

Comment: @Marcin That's an extremely poor reason to downvote someone.  This answer is clear, and while you don't approve of his choice in references, he took the time to answer this question.  These types of downvotes scare people away from wanting to participate on SO.

Comment: Seems a little unfair actually Marcin

Comment: @Tyrsius - See http://w3fools.com/. However, I agree that that's not reason for a downvote.

Comment: @James Allardice, thanks for that. I had heard nothing of that issue before.

Comment: I think it's perfectly fair to criticise the choice of a reference - after all, why should we reward people for linking to non-canonical sources which are known to harbour mistakes? We might as well award votes for giving answers which contain mistakes.

Comment: @Peter : Nope, I really did ask what the tags where used for and as all answers (thanks!) state, it is comments in a html-setting. :)

Answer (score 1):

lessthan-bang-dash-dash is a comment, which closes at dash-dash-greaterthan.

Answer (score 1):

Its a HTML comment, if you need further information http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp
;)

Answer (score 0):

The tags you posted in code are [Comment Tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp). They are for adding non-functional comments to code to help readers understand what is being done in the code.